# Binding Software

Tags: swig, language-binding, python-bindings

Is there a software for Language Bindings, other than SWIG. Also which is the most efficient ? I am looking for efficiency for C++ to Python bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 6 (main) alternatives when it comes to binding C++ and Python:

1. [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) - as you already know
2. [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/) - that was the advice of lefticus
3. [Cython](http://cython.org) - very neat syntax close to Python
4. [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) - not very much spread, but it is there
5. [PyBindGen](https://code.google.com/p/pybindgen/) - claims to be the fastest
6. [ECS:Python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecspython/) - new stuff

In terms of efficiency, I guess that will depend on what the task is. If you browse a bit around the net, you will see benchmarks around. PyBindGen folks are actually very proud of their system. You may want to start having a look there.

Particularly, I have experience with Boost.Python - easy to learn the simple tasks, a bit more tricky to do the complicated stuff. Normally generates code which is not the fastest from a function call overhead perspective, but it works beautifully. This one is very mature.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to efficiency, but the only other C++ to Python binding tool I am aware of is [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/index.html).